# Make Valid-Flags clearly distinguishable from Invalid-Flags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flag-history

Maybe it is just my eyes, but it is hard to scan your recent flags to tell what is `Valid` and what is `Invalid`. Can we highlight `Valid` in green or some other color to make it stand out?

Comment: thanks @Bobby for making the question clearer.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd rather have `Invalid`-Flags clearly stand out (not just the soft red text). If you have 100s of `Valid`-Flags, you might want to easily spot the one which you misplaced.

Comment: @Bobby: Good suggestion. I'd actually like both to stand out because if it is not flagged as Valid or Invalid, you still don't know what is pending.

Comment: I think it would be best if `Pending` and `Valid` flags should be...well, less dominant in the view. No one should care about `Valid` or `Pending` flags, those are just not that important (from a User-POV) like `Invalid` flags. To be honest, I always loved the `No news is good news`-approach, therefor I think it's best to keep everything which is OK in the background, and only make stuff you screwed up jump into your face and claw out your eyes.

Comment: @Bobby: Good analogy, but yes :) Maybe have it hidden, like in Visual Studio where you have regions and you can expand them.

Comment: Not necessarily hidden, but just not dominating or standing out like `Invalid` ones.

Comment: @Bobby: I'm tempted to agree with you about making flags marked a "invalid" more noticeable than the others, but I also dread the inevitable flood of Meta questions: "Why was my [perfectly valid] flag marked as invalid?" We get enough of those already. The last thing we need to do is encourage them by highlighting those in red.

Comment: @cody: by that logic, we shouldn't tell people that their question was closed

Comment: We no longer use `Valid/Invalid` on flags, I'm going to `status-declined` this.